# Why i cant display the image in flutter dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I cannot display the image, but all of the data is display for example name

```
    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: result.doc(foodId).get(),
      builder: ((context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data =
              snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Text('Name:' +
              '${data['name']}' +
              "\n"
                  'Description:' +
              '${data['description']}' +
              "\n"
                  'Energy:' +
              '+' +
              '${data['energy']}' +
              '${data['image']}');
        }
```

Comment: Does the key image exists inside data?

Comment: yes it is, in my firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this for displaying a network image:

```html
return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: result.doc(foodId).get(),
      builder: ((context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data =
              snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Image.network(data['image']);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you sir, now i can display my image from firebase

Answer (score 0):

You can not display image from the text widget, you need to use the image widget for that

```
return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    future: result.doc(foodId).get(),
    builder: ((context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data =
    snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text('Name:' +
        '${data['name']}' +
        "\n"
        'Description:' +
        '${data['description']}' +
        "\n"
        'Energy:' +
        '+' +
        '${data['energy']}' +
        '${data['image']}'),
        Image.network(data['image']),
      ],
    );
    }
```

Comment: Can you show me example code please? im new to flutter

Comment: to display image, use image widget like
Image.network('${data['image']}')